How to prevent IDA 8.4 from switching arm disassembly from thumb to arm modes on every instruction step
I am trying to debug a cortex-m0+ code using IDA, but on each step of code the debugger switches the disassembly from thumb mode to arm mode on its own.
I can't find any relevent option in IDA that stops it from happening, and I constantly need to set the mode manually (using alt+g).
Is there something that I'm missing?
I tried to tick No Automatic ARM-THUMB switch but it didn't change the debugger switching modes.
Edit:
looks like the thumb state bit in EPSR register stays set, which makes it even weirder because why would IDA decide that the code is in a different mode than the core.

MO does not support ARM instructions at all

right, but the problem isn't in the MCU but it's just in IDA trying to disassemble in ARM mode
